# how to add a right click menu on textBrowser placed on on a QDialog window using designer?

Tags: pyqt5, contextmenu

I am trying to implement a right click menu on a qtext browser:

```
import os
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtCore

FILE_LOCATION = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))


class MainDialogWindow(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainDialogWindow,self).__init__()
        ui_file = os.path.join(FILE_LOCATION, "example.ui")
        self._ui = uic.loadUi(ui_file, self)
        self.registerCallbacks()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        """Initialize the UI.
        """
        self.textBrowser.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)

    def registerCallbacks(self):
        self.connect(self.textBrowser, QtCore.Signal('customContextMenuRequested(const QPoint &)'), self.context_menu)

    def context_menu(self, event):
        menu = QMenu(self)
        menu.addAction("clear")
        menu.exec_(self.mapToGlobal(event.pos()))

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainDialogWindow()
    window.show()
    window.setGeometry(500, 300, 300, 300)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

here is the code I have written, but it throws error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 34, in <module>
    window = MainDialogWindow()
  File "example.py", line 14, in __init__
    self.registerCallbacks()
  File "example.py", line 23, in registerCallbacks
    self.connect(self.textBrowser, QtCore.Signal('customContextMenuRequested(const QPoint &)'), self.context_menu)
```

please help
    AttributeError: 'MainDialogWindow' object has no attribute 'connect'

new error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 29, in context_menu
    menu.exec_(self.mapToGlobal(event.pos()))
AttributeError: 'QPoint' object has no attribute 'pos'
Abort trap: 6
```

Comment: use `self.textBrowser.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.context_menu)`

Comment: cool now this worked but I got new error , I updated my op.

Comment: change to `menu.exec_(self.textBrowser.mapToGlobal(pos))` and `def context_menu(self, pos):`